# KeyboardAvoidingView is not working when using flex - React Native

Tags: react-native

> I have a Registration form with one form header and 3 input fileds.
>   When I am using KeyboardAvoidingView the deisgn is getting distorted.
>   My code is below:-

**Index.js code:-**

```
const Registration = (props)=>{
  return (

            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <Form submitForm={submitForm} />
            </SafeAreaView>

    )
}
```

**Form.js**

```
const Form = (props)=>{
 return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={[styles.headerTextContainer]}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                    Enter details to get started
                </Text>
            </View>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" style={styles.formContainer}>
                <View style={{flex:.20,marginBottom:25}}>
                        <View style={{flex:1.5,}}>
                                <Text style={styles.labelText}>First Name</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:3}}>
                                <TextInput
                                    value={userinfo.firstName}
                                    onChangeText={(text)=>setFormValue('firstName',text)}
                                    style={styles.input}
                                />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={styles.error}>{formError.first_name_error}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

> Corresponding css:-

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerTextContainer:{
        flex:.15,
        flexDirection:'column-reverse'
    },
    headerText:{
        color:'#000',
        fontSize:23,
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    formContainer:{
        flex:.75,
        padding:40
    },

    input:{
        height: 50, 
        borderColor: '#DFE4EB', 
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius:10
    },

    labelText:{
        color:'#BDBDBD',
        // marginLeft:12,
        marginBottom:10
    },

    buttonContainer:{
        flex:.20,
        alignContent:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        paddingLeft: 50,
        paddingRight: 50,
    }
})
```

**I am very new to react native. I am unable to find the problem in this code.I have tried changing the behaviour, but it does nothing.It will be helpful if any one can guide me about what I am doing wrong**

Here are the Images of the screen:-

[image]

[image]